# Paperclip uploaded files deleted?

Tags: ruby, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-5, capistrano

I uploaded few files using paperclip gem and now they are gone. I am wondering what caused the deletion of the uploaded files. According to the paperclip documentation.

> The files that are assigned as attachments are, by default, placed in
>   the directory specified by the :path option to has_attached_file. By
>   default, this location is
>   :rails_root/public/system/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename. This location was chosen because, on standard Capistrano deployments,
>   the public/system directory can be symlinked to the app's shared
>   directory, meaning it survives between deployments. For example, using
>   that :path, you may have a file at
>
> /data/myapp/releases/20081229172410/public/system/users/avatar/000/000/013/small/my_pic.png

I did few capistrano deployments after uploading the files but the uploaded files should survive. I am wondering what caused the files deletion. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are sharing the `public/system` directory between your releases. Otherwise each release will start with a blank slate.

```
# deploy.rb
append :linked_dirs, "public/system"
```